# Can I close Finder application?

Tags: finder, shortcut, force-quit

It looks like Finder can't be closed with `Command+Q` shortcut.

`Command+W` works though but it's not the same as `Command+Q`.

And there is not option for Finder to be closed whatsoever, only Hide.

[image]

Why is it so? Can I close Finder? How?

Comment: *Why* do you want to Quit Finder? - it's not meant to ever quit. It runs all the time the Mac is running.

Comment: You can quit the finder via the `terminal, but again why? see this and linked questions : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/304717/237687

Comment: @Tetsujin, well I didn't know that it's meant to run all the time